# Middleman helpers navigation class in HTML

Tags: ruby, middleman

I want to use a Middleman helper to add a class="selected" to a div. I see countless example to do this using one of Middleman's templating languages. Is there a way to do this in plan HTML?

config.rg

```
helpers do
  def is_page_selected(page)
    current_page.url == page ? {:class => "selected"} : {}
  end
end
```

_header.erb

```
<div class="header_menu_item <%= is_page_selected("/dashboard.html") %>">Dashboard</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Not to my knowledge. What prevents you from using something like ERB?

Comment: I'm converting a rather large project to use Middleman and don't want to convert everything to HAML. Is there anything preventing a HTML/HAML mix?

Comment: Well, your best bet should be ERB, as it is pure HTML enriched with Ruby. The example you gave above shows it actually quite good. Just paste your existing pure HTML in a template (say `example.html.erb`) and you should not run in any problems. You can then add some programatic behavior (like the navigation class helpers) to help you DRY your templates. See http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/ for a starter on ERB, it really will help you in the long run.

Comment: Mixing HTML and HAML worked best. Just converted the navigation HTML to a HAML partial to use the Middleman helper. #Fixed

Answer (score 1):

You can use ERB just fine in Middleman. Your example would work if your helper was:

```
helpers do
  def is_page_selected(page)
    current_page.url == page ? "selected" : ''
  end
end
```

Then:

```
<div class="header_menu_item <%= is_page_selected("/dashboard.html") %>">Dashboard</div>
```